# Keyboard interaction

Tags: python, aiogram

Please help me solve the problem of writing a bot on aiogram. The very essence is as follows. There is a settings menu where you can choose a currency from the presented list (I will attach a screenshot below). When you click any of the buttons, the value of the selected currency should be passed to the usual menu button. If you can then with examples, I will be grateful, or tell me in which direction to move.. In the end, you should get BTC/RUB, BTC/KZT, etc.

[image]

code handler:

```
@dp.message_handler(Command(commands=['set']))
async def setting_menu(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("⚙ Settings", reply_markup=staye)
    await message.answer(f"{message.from_user.first_name}, you are in the settings.\n\n"
                         f"Select the currency of interest in the menu below.\n"
                         reply_markup=set_menu)
```

code inline keyboard:

```
set_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1,
                                inline_keyboard=[
                                    [
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(
                                            text="RUB",
                                            callback_data='1'
                                        ),
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(
                                            text="UAH",
                                            callback_data='2'
                                        ),
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(
                                            text="USD",
                                            callback_data='3'
                                        ),
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(
                                            text="KZT",
                                            callback_data='4'
                                        ),
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(
                                            text="BYN",
                                            callback_data='5'
                                        ),
                                    ]
                                ])
```

default keyboard code:

```
staye = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
course = KeyboardButton(text="BTC/....")
course1 = KeyboardButton(text="test1")
course2 = KeyboardButton(text="test2")
staye.add(course, course1, course2)
```

Answer (score 1):

After user clicks on inline button (RUB, USD, etc), you should send message with new ReplyMarkup.
There are no any ways to change Keyboard text without sending new message or edit existing one
To implement different keyboard text, you can do something like

```
def get_reply_markup(currency: str) -> ReplyKeyboardMarkup:
    staye = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
    course = KeyboardButton(text=currency)
    course1 = KeyboardButton(text="test1")
    course2 = KeyboardButton(text="test2")
    staye.add(course, course1, course2)
```

This "currency" you can get from inline keyboard callback.
After that:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(*Your filtering*)
async def handler(call: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    currency = callback_data.get('currency')
    keyboard = get_reply_markup(currency)
    await call.message.answer(text='Some text', reply=keyboard)
    await call.answer()
```